# Signalr uanble to establish connection to .net core app

Tags: angular, .net-core, signalr

I am using ASP.NET Core 3.1 and have installed -

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR -Version 1.1.0
```

Angular version 7 and have installed-

```
npm install @microsoft/signalr --save
```

Url generated at server side are -

```
https://localhost:33299/region1/api/Products
https://localhost:33299/region1/api/Users
```

here region1 is the area and right now, we have only 1 area.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {  
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                var origins = Configuration["AllowedOrigins"].Split(";");
                options.AddPolicy(AllowedOrigins,
                builder =>
                {                    
                    builder.WithOrigins(origins).SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains().AllowAnyHeader()
                        .WithMethods(new[] { "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS" });
                });
            });
            services.AddSignalR();
            services.ConfigureLoggerService();
            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
            services.AddSession();
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Latest);
            // configure strongly typed settings objects
            services.AddConfigurationService(Configuration);
            services.AddSwaggerDocumentation(Configuration);
            services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
            ConfigurationServiceExtension.ConfigureExceptionLogger(Configuration);
        }
```

and this is my configure method-

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            if (env.EnvironmentName == configuration["EnvironmentVariable"])
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseCors(AllowedOrigins);
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseRouting();          
            app.UseAuthentication();
            //global exception handling extension
            app.ConfigureCustomExceptionMiddleware();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            //Swagger document settings extension method
            app.UseSwaggerDocumentation(env.EnvironmentName == configuration["EnvironmentVariable"], Configuration);
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {              
                // Which is the same as the template
               endpoints.MapControllerRoute("areaRoutes", "{area:exists}/{controller=Project}/{action=Get}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapHub<ChartHub>("/Products");
            });
        }
```

and lastly my controller code,

```
[Area("region1")]
    [Route("[area]/api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Authorize]
    public class ProductsController : BaseApiController
    {
        private readonly IHubContext<ChartHub> _hub;

        public ProductsController(IHubContext<ChartHub> hub)
        {
            _hub = hub;
        }
        
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("Get")]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            var timerManager = new TimerManager(() => _hub.Clients.All.SendAsync("transferchartdata", GetRealTimeData()));
            return Ok(new { Message = "Request Completed" });
        }
    }
```

At Angular side, this is my service to establish connection-

```
private hubConnection: signalR.HubConnection
  public startConnection = () => {
    this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
                            .withUrl('https://localhost:33299/Products', {
                              //skipNegotiation: true,
                              // transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets
                            })
                           // .withAutomaticReconnect()
                            .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Debug)
                            .build();
    this.hubConnection
      .start()
      .then(() => console.log('Connection started'))
      .catch(err => console.log('Error while starting connection: ' + err))
  }
  public addTransferChartDataListener = () => {
    this.hubConnection.on('transferchartdata', (data) => {
      this.data = data;
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
```

Have tried almost everything, this is something related to cors or the area region1 which is coming in between the url.
I was following this tutorial to implement signal R in my application.  https://code-maze.com/netcore-signalr-angular/

console messages which i am getting-

```
[2021-07-26T13:03:04.177Z] Debug: Selecting transport 'WebSockets'.
[2021-07-26T13:03:04.382Z] Information: WebSocket connected to wss://localhost:33299/Products?id=Ny16wQtzfPICUJ6s8mm-9w.
[2021-07-26T13:03:04.383Z] Debug: The HttpConnection connected successfully.
[2021-07-26T13:03:04.384Z] Debug: Sending handshake request.
[2021-07-26T13:03:04.391Z] Information: Using HubProtocol 'json'.
[2021-07-26T13:03:04.511Z] Debug: Server handshake complete.
[2021-07-26T13:03:04.516Z] Debug: HubConnection connected successfully.
SignalRService.service.ts:24 Connection started
starthttpReq {message: "Request Completed"}
[2021-07-26T13:03:15.204Z] Debug: HttpConnection.stopConnection(undefined) called while in state Connected.
[2021-07-26T13:03:15.206Z] Information: Connection disconnected.
[2021-07-26T13:03:15.209Z] Debug: HubConnection.connectionClosed(undefined) called while in state Connected.
```

Any kind of hint or help will be beneficial.

Comment: The the SignalR connection from angular work with this URL: `'https://localhost:33299/Products'`? Or do you at least get a different error than a CORS error with this URL?

Comment: @R.Richards same message Access to fetch at 'https://localhost:33299/Products/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1' from origin 'https://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. just url part changes

Comment: Is `http://localhost:4200` in the *AllowedOrigins* configuration?

Comment: Yes, it is already working from last 2 years

Comment: @R.Richards, ur trick works but it get connected and then disconnected within 2 sec. i added log code so it giving msg 'Debug: HttpConnection.stopConnection(undefined) called while in state Connected.'

Comment: SignalR is part of the aspnet core framework. You shouldn't use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR`.

Comment: @R.Richards,i have edited the question and provided the console messages also

Comment: @NoahStahl so should i remove it and then try ?

Comment: Try doing a search on the messages you are getting. There is no need for a repost.